# DRM support in android

Tags: android, drm, android-drm

My question is based on DRM.

A) does android support DRM ?
B) If Yes how to use DRM in android?
C) who are the content providers ?

Actually I want develop an android application, that downloads any content like audio, video from content provider and I want that content to be protected with my application from the user i.e user should use it but not forward or modify it . please help me on this.

Thanks
Shiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DRM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary.html) support is added in API level 11.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur replay. Can u ans for my third question? how can i get contents with rights to protect from user?

Comment: @Shiv - They are such as online stores (to control how the digital music and video files you obtain from them are used and distributed.) They sell and rent songs and movies that have DRM applied to them.

Comment: Ok thank u AVD. but i am not getting that kind of online store. can u tel me one sit

Answer (score 1):

A) does android support DRM ?
Yes, it does.the most common solution is widewine recently.
It depends on OEM if they support it or not.
the latest Nexus phone or tablet should support it.

B) If Yes how to use DRM in android?
it's better to refer to 
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer
about how to use widewine

C) who are the content providers ?
Actually you don't need to know who is the content provider.
Who encrypts the content should be the content provider in this meaning.
There are some sample video hosted by google in exoplayer file ,which you could use it for testing.